# How to add a vm to multiple azure automation hybrid worker group

Tags: azure, azure-automation

We have one azure vm (jump server) which is already part of our staging hybrid worker group.

Now I want to add it to our prod hybrid worker group which is in different azure subscription. Is there any way to keep both?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently in Azure Automation, A hybrid worker can only point to one automation account. There's already a request to the Azure Automation team to support this scenario. I recommend you Upvote the feedback @ https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/33608410-utilize-the-same-automation-hybrid-runbook-workers

Comment: This link has succumbed to link rot, and was not archived by web.archive.org.